# Is there any equivalent swprintf in QString?

Tags: c++, qt

We are migrating an application from windows(CE)-ARM to Linux-ARM.

We are using `Qt4.8`. Usually wchar is 4 bytes in linux environment but in windows(CE) it is 2 bytes. Because of memory concern we rebuilt the gcc and glibc as 2 bytes wchar.

swprintf does not work properly for 2 bytes. We found that QString can handle the 2 bytes wchar properly.

Below is customized wsprintf function definition. This is wrapper function for the windows wsprintf to linux.

```
    **Function definition**
    int wsprintf(wchar_t* f_wszOutData, wchar_t* f_wszformat, ...)  
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args,f_wszFormat);
        QString l_QszOutBuffer;
        QString l_QszFormat=QString::fromWCharArray(f_wszFormat);
        QByteArray l_QByteArray=l_QszFormat.toAscii();
        l_QszOutBuffer.vsprintf(l_QByteArray.data(),args);
        l_QszOutBuffer.toWCharArray(f_wszOutData);
        va_end(args);
        return l_QszOutBuffer.length(); 
    } 

    **Function Call**
    wchar_t l_wszOutput[200];
    wsprintf(l_wszOutput,L"%d %lf %s %ls", 78,89.90,"Hello world",L"world");

    **Output**
    78 89.900000 Hello world w
```

Currently QString's vsprintf() supports char*, int, double, etc. But wchar_t* is not supported. so, the last parameter is not printed properly. Is there any support for formatting the wchar_t* in QString's vsprintf() ? Is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: If memory usage is your concern, wouldn't it be easier to use utf-8 with single byte chars?

Comment: In our application most of string operations are done using the wchar_t*. When migrating from windows(CE) to linux, we decided that to avoid modifying the business logic source code for reducing the testing effort. Our testing scope mostly on wrapper classes alone.
We have many concerns in Windows(CE) source to linux. 
I.e  we used the memset, memcpy for wchar_t instead of wmemset, wmemcpy, 
             etc. we used memset like 'memset(wcharVariable,0,size*2)', 
     wide character's initalization and copy is done like L"wide characters", 
     etc.

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to use `QString::toAscii`, as it rarely does what one expects or wants, which is also why it is marked as obsolete in the current versions.

Comment: Also, this line: `QString l_QszFormat=QString::fromWCharArray();` looks like it shouldn't compile. To avoid confusion and getting sidetracked, please provide working code in the question, even if you aren't asking about actual bug in the code and are providing just an example.

Comment: Oh, and it strikes me as a bit... contradictory, if you are using Qt, and especially Qt4, to save memory over standard library... For example, I don't think Qt4 QString "literals" can be constructed at compile time, they require extra heap allocation done at runtime.

Comment: I have updated the working code with actual bug. yes, we used the Qt4